# CentOS repository for PHP 5.3.8 or higher?

Tags: php, centos

Anyone know where I might find such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/ if you are on CentOS 5 it has 5.3.10

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. If you're trying for PCI certification you'll need to be on PHP 5.3.8 or higher.

Comment: @SeamusJames no prob if, it ends up working be sure and mark this as the answer so others having the same problem will know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I use remi collet, at the moment he has php 5.3.x but will upgrade to php 5.4 on 15 december 2012

The  url is http://rpms.famillecollet.com/

Answer (score 0):

Another fix for the Dag Wieers repository...

http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php#B

Install this and you can just yum install it (as well as a ton of other stuff)..